# Why don't properties lazily instantiate by default?

Tags: objective-c, properties

Up until now I thought that the @property directive generated a getter that `..alloc] init]`'d its respective object, and now I don't understand why this is not part of the language. Even worse- there is no exception when a nil property is accessed.

I feel like there's a misconception somewhere in my reasoning, but I don't know where. I'd like to know why having a auto-lazy-instantiator as part of properties would not be ideal for almost all cases in Cocoa development.

Comment: Sometimes you **want** a property to be `nil` and return `nil` when accessed. This would not work with lazy instantiation.

Comment: Yeah, good point. Well, for auto-lazy loading to exist without conflict, there would need to be a way to check if an object had been set explicitly. If my assumptions are not flawed, adding some code to the NSObject metaclass could implement my proposition.

Comment: I'll note here that my frustration comes from forgetting to lazily load (or initialize in the `init` method) arrays, and then searching for a silent bug when adding to my array has no effect. It's real punishment for forgetting to modify the accessor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Properties are a fairly new feature of Objective-C. A great deal of existing code assumes that ivars initialize to 0, and so object getters start as `nil`. The implementation of properties was built to implement the same type of accessors that most people had been writing by hand (or by using tools like [Accessorizer](http://www.kevincallahan.org/software/accessorizer.html)). Most people did not create lazy getters by hand, so properties weren't implemented this way either. It's a specialized problem, not the common need.

(Side note: my claim here is somewhat belied by the fact that `atomic` was made the default, which was not the most common way to write accessors by hand. But it was compatible with common ways of writing accessors, just slower, and some people did routinely write atomic accessors. Laziness would not be compatible.)

There are many cases when you would not want this behavior at all. I wouldn't want an `-image` property to automatically generate an empty `UIImage`. I would rather get `nil` back if nothing is assigned. In many cases, there is a significant difference between "empty" and `nil`. A `nil` title may mean "use the default" while `@""` might mean "be empty." This is a pretty common pattern. I don't write lazy accessors very often (but partially because it's a hassle to do so.)

There are several classes for which `init` is not the designated initializer, and may not even be a sensible (or even legal) initializer.

But it might be a useful option for properties, such as:

```
@property (nonatomic, lazy, readwrite, strong) NSMutableArray *stuff;
```

If you'd find that often useful, you should open a radar at bugreport.apple.com.

Regarding the fact it is legal to message `nil` in ObjC, that goes back to the very beginning. Often it's extremely handy (it gets rid of a lot of error-checking code). Sometimes it is the source of very annoying bugs (sometimes you still need to do the error-checking, and it's not always obvious when). But it is not likely to change. It's a fundamental part of the language.

Comment: Oh my goodness a `lazy` property attribute is pure gold- good thinking! That's way more practical than a default. I just submitted a feature request bug report.

Answer (score 4):

Almost all standard read/write properties are assigned from outside the class. There is no need for lazy instantiation in such cases. The property simply holds whatever value may have been assigned. If no value is assigned, you get `nil`. This is all normal usage. So the normal synthesized getter returns whatever value may be assigned. The standard synthesized setter just holds on to the assigned value taking care of proper memory management and some KVO.

If you want a getter to return some internal, lazy loaded value, then that is a behavior that is specific to your need for that property. You need to implement your own custom getter to provide that behavior. This is far less common than most simple properties.

Comment: Your answer makes sense. But I'm curious- the only trade-off of auto lazy loading is preventing properties from being nil, right (Since they don't hang in memory until referenced)? And if it was simple enough to check a property for having been set through the setter instead of nil-checking (I guess my suggested feature is actually 2 features), then wouldn't all interactions with properties enjoy far less esoteric boilerplate?

Comment: Auto-lazy loading doesn't make sense for most properties. Why would you lazy load a simple `BOOL`, `int`, or `NSString` property? Lazy loading only makes sense on more complicated properties where the initial access needs to load a bunch of data into memory. This is far less common than the simple properties.

Comment: Yeah, it really doesn't work well with the primitives. I'm starting to understand what the reason is to not have it. Maybe I should've posited that sending a message to `nil` should log something...

Comment: Messaging nil is a very, very common practice in ObjC, not just in user code but inside the libraries. If it logged something, your logs would explode. In OS X, there is a undocumented hook for debugging purposes, but it was not ported to iOS (it's very hard to make this very useful even on Mac). http://www.friday.com/bbum/2008/01/02/objective-c-logging-messages-to-nil/